# Can no claims bonus be transferred from UK to Australia?

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, car, insurance, car-insurance

I have no claims bonus on my car insurance in UK which drops my premium substantially, there is possibility of me ending up in Australia...

I am sure I am not first person to move and I was wondering has anyone successfully moved their no claims bonus to Australian insurance company (or this is unheard of)?

**Can no claims bonus be transferred from UK to Australia?**

Comment: Does your insurance company operate in Australia? Have you asked them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending on the company.

There are [several](http://britishexpats.com/forum/australia-54/car-insurance-uk-no-claims-discounts-642879/) of [examples](https://www.pomsinoz.com/topic/86013-no-claims-bonus-in-the-uk-using-australian-no-claims-bonus-for-car-insurance/) online [stating](http://www.britzinoz.com/motoring-transfer-uk-no-claim-discount-to-australia) just this.

From the last link:

> Many Australian Insurers will accept your British No Claims Discount,
>   and some do not even need to see it, unless you have a claim.
>
> At that point they will need it, and if you don’t have it, then
>   technically they could invalidate your insurance, on the grounds that
>   you gave them false information.  If you have the proof, give them a
>   copy as soon as you can to cover that eventuality.

Note however, that some Australian insurers don't have No Claim Bonuses anyway.

Comment: I similarly was able to use a US no-claims bonus (USAA) when I moved the the UK (Direct Line).